# $E=mc^2$ maybe has something wrong in it

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, mass-energy

Whenever I simplify $E^2=mc^2+(pc)^2 $,
I end up with $0.7072E=mc^2$.How?
Its like-
$e^2=(mc^2)^2 + pc^2,
[p=m*v (v=c)],
$e^2=2$(mc^2)^2,
$e=1.414mc^2,
0.7072e=mc^2.

IS it enough?

Comment: How are you getting the .7072?

Answer (score 9):

$E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$ is the correct relation. To see this, perform some dimensional analysis on your equation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with $E=mc^2$,  except that it is a different **m** than the one entering the $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$  relation.

The first relation should be written $E=m_rc^2$ where $m_r$ is the relativistic mass, [look it up,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass) which is velocity dependent,  a concept introduced to be analogous to the [inertial mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mass.html) used in classical mechanics, i.e. mass as a resistance to force/change. In the second formula the m is the invariant mass, characteristic of any [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) in special relativity. It is the corresponding "length" of the four vector and is invariant under Lorenz transformations. Particles are characterized by their invariant mass.

Comment: Although the inertial mass is direction dependent: inertia against a shove at right angles to the motion equals the relativistic mass, whereas inertia against a shove along the motion is $\gamma^3\,m_0$. So, although that was the original idea, you can't really make it compatible with an inertial mass idea.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance  I mean compatible with the concept that there is resistance to a force, not the exact format. I guess definition 1 in webster.com. I will try "analogous"